# Como definir widht 100% apenas para o col-xs?

Tags: bootstrap-3

Olá. No col-md e col-lg o widht está 50% e que eu quero mais. Porém no col-xs e col-sm os blocos ficam lado a lado e não abaixo do outro como quero. Como resolver?

Comment: colocar a classe `col-xs-12` não resolve?

Comment: acabei de resolver, amigo. obrigado